# Pointers Accessing Incorrect Addresses OS161

Tags: c, operating-system, os161

I'm using OS161, and I have a piece of code that looks like this in `process.c`:

```
void
process_exit(int exit_code)
{
   splhigh(); 
    curthread->p_process->exited_flag = 1; // Process exited
    curthread->p_process->exit_code = exit_code;
    struct process * process;

    // Now all the child process will be orphant, we need to adopt them
    // Search through the process table, change all children's ppid

    for (int i = 0; i < array_getnum(process_table); i++) {
        *process = array_getguy(process_table, i);
        if (process != NULL && process->ppid == curthread->p_process->pid) { // We found a child here, it should be a orphant now
            process->ppid = 1; // Now the init(boot/menu) process should adopt the child process
            process->adopted_flag = 1;
        }
    }

    V(curthread->p_process->sem_exit); // Now signal processes which are waiting

    // Now exit the thread
    thread_exit();


}
```

The definition of process struct:

```
struct process{

char* process_name;

struct addrspace *process_vmspace;


struct vnode *process_cwd;

pid_t pid;
pid_t ppid;
int adopted_flag;
int exited_flag;
int exit_code;
struct thread *p_thread;
struct semaphore *sem_exit;
};
```

I'm getting an `END OF FILE` error, and GDB told me it was where `process_exit` was defined. I'm not super familiar with OS programming, does anyone know why this could be happening?

Edit: This was the GDB message:

```
panic: Fatal exception 3 (TLB miss on store) in kernel mode
panic: EPC 0x8001a008, exception vaddr 0x18
sleep: Dropping thread <boot/menu>
panic: I can't handle this... I think I'll just die now...
```

I did `gdb list *0x8001a008` and it pointed to the `curthread->p_process->exited_flag = 1;`.

Comment: Does `gdb` indicate a precise line number in *process_exit()*?  Maybe it merely indicates "somewhere in process_exit" (which doesn't seem like gdb at all).  Maybe you are having trouble interpreting the gdb message?  If so, please amend your question to post the exact message displayed.

Comment: Either `curthread` or `curthread->p_process` was NULL. Probably.

Comment: I am not familiar with OS161 and surprised that a simple teaching OS would bother with TLBs; I wonder if the *TLB cache miss* is the more immediate pathology.

Comment: @wallyk Well, if the underlying hardware only supports software-managed TLBs, the OS doesn't have much choice

Answer (score 1):

Given @ctx's analysis, try this code to prove whether we're on the right track:

```
void
process_exit(int exit_code)
{
    splhigh();
    if (curthread  &&  curthread->p_process)
    {
        curthread->p_process->exited_flag = 1; // Process exited
        curthread->p_process->exit_code = exit_code;
    }
    // same code as before below here ...
```